# BrowserSync error: "You tried to start BrowserSync twice"

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync, gulp-connect-php

This script works and refreshes my page, and runs all the tasks I have set up, but it gives me "You tried to start BrowserSync twice" in my terminal every time it runs.

As far as I've researched, the cause should be the `browserSync.reload` I've added in the `gulp.watch` task, but when I remove it, it gives me "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function." When I look on Github to find other examples for setting up BrowserSync they are all written slightly different so I can't get a real grasp on the syntax.

It's not a critical error, but it is a pesky alert.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var php = require('gulp-connect-php');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');


gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('image-min', function () {
    gulp.src('assets/images/src/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/images/dist/'))
});

gulp.task('php', function() {
    php.server({ base: '../drive4innovative.com', port: 8080, keepalive: true});
});

gulp.task('browser-sync',['php'], function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'localhost/drive4innovative.com/',
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
});

    gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass', 'image-min'], function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/css/*.scss', [sass]);
    gulp.watch('**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Unrelated note: In your `watch` task, there should be quotes around `sass` in order to reference the `sass` task. Without that, it's going to be pointing to `gulp-sass`.

Comment: Check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281597/gulp-connect-php-browsersync-gulp-connect-address-in-use-issue). Your issue could be with the way you start the server, not with `gulp.watch`.

Comment: I would try var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); and browserSync.init({ in your task and see if that helps - especially the .init